# Чем грамотно парсить html в java

Tags: html, java, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

В проекте мне приходит HTML код строкой String.
Из него надо определенные блоки убрать и некоторые добавить. Слышал, что есть какой-то граммотный класc для подобного, но никак не могу найти нужную информацию...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить?

p.s. не очень хочется писать громоздкий код вручную.

Comment: [сойдет ?][1]


  [1]: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: на jsoup я натыкался, но мне так слишком... мне приходит только строка ,а не заниматься выковыриванием кода с простора интернета.

но спс.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: а более локально? кто-то использовал [этот класс][1]??


  [1]: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement.html

Comment: @Simkhoptech Что значит более локально? В Getting started есть примеры. Начните с класса http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если это XHTML - то есть кусок валидного XML'а то проще использовать стандартный SAX

**P.S.** Кстати, вырубив проверку валидности - можно и для обычного HTML'а использовать SAX

Comment: у меня всего лишь HTML...